# Evaluating complex integral $\int _{\left|z\right|=2}^{ }\:\frac{e^z}{z-1}dz$ using the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to solve $\int _{\left|z\right|=2}^{ }\:\frac{e^z}{z-1}dz$ using the residue theorem and keep getting $-4\pi i$, which is evidently wrong. I would greatly appreciate any helpful hints.

Comment: Why don't you show us your solution, so we can see what (if anything) went wrong there? And I don't see what hints I can give here, just use Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Try it with [Cauchy's differentiation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) with $f(z)=e^z,n=0,a=1$. Now try again and include your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\left(z\right)=\frac{e^z}{z-1}$. Then f has has a simple pole at $z0=1$, $Res\left(f,1\right)=\lim _{z\to 1}\left(z-1\right)\frac{e^z}{z-1}=\lim _{z\to 1}e^z=e$. Hence, $\int _{\left|z\right|=1}^{ }\:f\left(z\right)dz=2\pi iRes\left(f,1\right)=2\pi ie$. By the way, thank you for the advice, I just solved the integral by Cauchy's theorem, but this is the answer provided under residue solution, so I just decided to post it here for reference.